# Joined member avatar displayed in thumbnail of embed

Tags: javascript

so i tried User Avatar shows up in Thumbnail here's my code

```
  if (generalChannel) {
    await lib.discord.channels['@0.0.3'].messages.create({
      channel_id: generalChannel.id,
      "content": "",
      "tts": false,
      "embed": {
        "type": "rich",
        "title": `Rage Of Destiny`,
        "description": `<@!${event.user.id}> Welcome to the Official Rage Of Destiny Discord Server! \n\nWe hope you enjoy your stay\n\nRemember to read #rules unless you wan't Thordin  to punish you `,
        "color": 0xff2200,
        "image": {
          "url": `https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/854601844905738260/866527689720070154/welcome-left.jpeg`,
          "height": 0,
          "width": 0
        },
        "thumbnail": {
          "url": `(message.author.avatarURL())`,
          "height": 0,
          "width": 0
        }
      }
    });
  }

};
```

but this is not working, did try to search about it but nothing

```
    "thumbnail": {
      "url": `(message.author.avatarURL())`,
      "height": 0,
      "width": 0
    }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.  What does 'not working' mean?  Can you find an error message which is relevant to your problem?

Comment: As morric stated, what do you mean by "not working"? can you [elaborate more](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)?